# Shopify / Liquid find "-" and remove and content before

Tags: html, smarty, shopify, liquid

I have some content, for example: Product Type - Colour Name (this changes but always the same format, I want to just display the "Colour Name"

It is outputted with:

```
{{ product.title }}
```

What I need to do is use the available string filters and find and remove "-" and the content before it so it just displays the part after the  hyphen "-"

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [the `split` filter.](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters#split)

```
{% assign words = product.title | split: ' - ' %}
{{ words[1] }}
```